# How to define and use a Custom Attribute in PowerShell 5?

Tags: .net, powershell

Using PowerShell `5.1.14393.3866` on Windows 10, I am trying to define and use custom attributes on Powershell class properties as in the following:

```
class MarkedAttribute : System.Attribute { }

class Person {
    [Marked()]
    [string]$Name
}

$p = [Person]::new()
$p.Name = "Hoho"

Write-Host $p.Name
```

When I run the previous script I get the following error:

```
At C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Desktop\FinishLine\issue.ps1:6 char:6
+     [Marked()]
+      ~~~~~~
Cannot find the type for custom attribute 'Marked'. Make sure that the assembly that contains this type is loaded.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CustomAttributeTypeNotFound
```

It is as if the custom attribute was never defined.

I am able to use 'standard' attributes such as the ones defined in [System.ComponentModel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel?view=net-5.0) but no chance with custom attributes.

I tried the following **without success:**

- Using the full attribute name `[MarkedAttribute()]`
- Defining the attribute in C# and executing `Add-Type -TypeDefinition $theCsCode`

According to [some posts on the web](https://powershell.one/powershell-internals/attributes/custom-attributes), it should be possible to use custom attribute from PowerShell.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems (written as of PowerShell 7.1):

- Class definitions are processed at parse time, at which point any referenced types must already be defined; that is, the `[MarkedAttribute]` type must be defined *before* the `[Person]` type can be declared with a reference to it.

  - To work around that in a single script, you need [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression), though do note that [`Invoke-Expression` should generally be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/)
- Once that requirement is met, additionally - for reasons unknown to me - the explicit `Attribute` suffix is needed to refer to the type.

  - This unexpected additional requirement is discussed in [GitHub issue #14499](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14499).

```
class MarkedAttribute : System.Attribute { }

# Use Invoke-Expression so you can refer to [MarkedAttribute] if defined
# in the same script, 
# and be sure to use the 'Attribute' suffix explicitly.
Invoke-Expression @'
  class Person {
    [MarkedAttribute()]
    [string]$Name
  }
'@

$p = [Person]::new()
$p.Name = "Hoho"

$p.Name # output
```

---

If you want to avoid the need for `Invoke-Expression`, outsource the `[Person]` class definition to a separate file that you can then load into the current scope with `.`, the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-):

First, create a `PersonClass.ps1` file containing the `Person` class definition in the same directory as the script that will be using it:

```
@'
class Person {
  [MarkedAttribute()]
  [string]$Name
}
'@ > PersonClass.ps1
```

Then define your main script as follows:

```
class MarkedAttribute : System.Attribute { }

# Dot-source the script that defines the [Person] class, from the
# same dir. where this script resides:
. $PSScriptRoot/PersonClass.ps1

$p = [Person]::new()
$p.Name = "Hoho"

$p.Name # output
```

This approach ensures that class `[MarkedAttribute]` is already defined by the time `PersonClass.ps1` is parsed, and the definition of `[Person]` therefore succeeds.